# convergence of norm with respect to the order of sobolev norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in BV(I)$, $I=(0,1)$ be given. By Evans & Gariepy we know that there exists a sequence $u_n\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ such that $|u'_n|_{L^{1}(I)}\to |u|_{TV(I)}$ where we use $TV$ to denote the total variation.

My question: do I have $|u'_n|_{L^{1+1/n}(I)}\to |u|_{TV(I)}$ as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Why should the $L^{1+1/n}$-norm be bounded at all? You should try to come up with a counterexample;

Comment: @daw since $u_n\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ so for each $u_n$ it is bounded. Say if $u$ itself is good, then it is good. So I am thinking to use sth like approximation

Comment: It's true if you pass to a subsequence. That is, there exists $k_n \to \infty$ such that $|u_n'|_{L^{1+1/k_n}} \to |u|_{TV(I)}$. Use a diagonal argument. It's not true as you've written it. As a counterexample take a sequence of piecewise linear functions converging (slowly enough) to a step function.

Comment: @Jeff understood. a subsequence is all I need. Thank you!